# Something is hiding behind in Reports and Dashboard. How to reveal it?

Tags: reporting, dashboard, pagination

I tried to see all the reports in the org, but I think the paging part is hiding and am not able to access it. Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reducing the zoom on the browser ? Ctrl minus